# Python permutations based on a Dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary saved as a TXT file which contains one word per line. What I want to do is to generate all the permutations of those words, by joining them (no spaces, no commas, nothing, pure join).

Example:

Alex

Boby

Cris

Output: AlexAlex, AlexBoby, AlexCris, BobyAlex, BobyBoby, BobyCris, CrisAlex, CrisBoby, CrisCris

Each individual permutation will be used for the rest of the program.

Until now i have this:

```
with open('file.txt','rb') as text:
    for entry in text.readlines():
        variable = entry
```

Which allows me to get each line and store in in a variable which I can use afterwards.

But I can't figure these permutations... Can somebody help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably just because you googled the wrong term. That's not permutations, that's product.

Comment: `xs = ["Alex", "Bobby", "Chris"]; list(itertools.product(xs, xs))`

Answer (score 0):

Given a file 'file.txt' with the names as presented in your example

Alex

Boby

Cris

```
words = []

with open('file.txt', "r") as text:
    for line in text:
        words.extend(line.split())


print(words)
```

output:

```
['Alex', 'Boby', 'Cris']
```

Now converting the list into your permutations

```
permutations = [i+j for i in words for j in words]

print(permutations)
```

output:

```
['AlexAlex', 'AlexBoby', 'AlexCris', 'BobyAlex', 'BobyBoby', 'BobyCris', 'CrisAlex', 'CrisBoby', 'CrisCris']
```

Comment: How do I associate the words from the .txt file to the words variable?

Comment: @ChiserAlexandru, I have ammended the answer to include this. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.txt','rb') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

all_permutations = [''.join(x) for x in itertools.permutations(lines)]
```

Comment: I tried this stuff:
`with open('Dictionar.txt','rb') as text1:
    for entry1 in text1.readlines():
        with open('Dictionar.txt','rb') as text2:
            for entry2 in text2.readlines():
               password = entry1 + entry2`

But the password ends up like this when I print it: b'entry1\nentry2\n

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand your comment. Please put code parts in code. The answer is not working ?

Comment: Basically I tried using 2 entries, which read from the same files. Then I joined these entries using the + symbol, but the final result ends up like this: b'entry1\nentry2\n. And I have new lines in the result. I need to remove these new lines.

Comment: That is why I have `.rstrip()` called. You can do `password = entry1.rstrip() + entry2.rstrip()`. If the answer is working, please accept it.